# Newline every 7 lines within a for loop

Tags: java, loops, newline

I can already achieve this by using:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < amount i++){
    if(i == 7 | i == 14 i == 21 | etc..){
    System.out.prinf(i + "\n");
    }
    else{
    System.out.printf(i);
    }
```

I want to follow the DRY rules to print a new line every 7 lines. Is there a better solution??

```
    1 2 3 4 5 6 7
    8 9 10 11 12 13 14
    15 16 17 18 19 20 21
    etc..
```

Comment: You can use `(i % 7 == 0)` to check if a number is a multiple of 7.

Comment: Wow that was easy lol.. Thanks alot :)

Comment: @Carcigenicate: This isn't quite the same as OP's code in that it also matches zero.

Comment: @NPE Corner cases can be covered separately. The "multiple of 7" aspect is the main part. It looks like they don't want 0 included at all though, so I think their example code is wrong, or the example output is.

Answer (score 1):

Yes:

```
if (i % 7 == 0 && i != 0) {
```

This evaluates to `true` for every line that's zero *modulo seven* except zero.

Comment: thanks for the answer!

Comment: @AuronKelmud: Please see the updated answer. The original solution included zero, whereas your code didn't.

Comment: Ok I see it thanks